# Buffering progress gone from YouTube

Tags: youtube, video-streaming

When playing a video on YouTube the light-red buffering progress no longer appears, though the rest of the UI works as usual. Buffering still happens, it just doesn't display its progress.

[image: no buffering]

I'm not sure if this is intentional by YouTube or not, but in any case, how can I make it visible again?

I'm using Firefox on Windows 7, with Flashblock, as a signed-in user. Trying the recommended solution by Google to generic YouTube problems - which is emptying the browser cache - didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the cookies for Youtube

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

No repro for me.

Tested using FireFox (with Flashbox installed) and Chrome.

[image]

Comment: Good for you, but... this isn't an answer.

Comment: @Oak: I have posted this as an answer so that the image is displayed. How do you know that the buffering is happening/complete? If everything is working as you'd expect why do you even need/care about the buffering progress bar? I think this question is too localized in any case.

Comment: Well, (1) I already know how the buffer bar *should* look like - I think that's evident from the question, and (2) not everything is working as expected - the progress bar is missing, and despite the fact that buffering still works, this is a significant usability loss, at least in my eyes. I don't see anything which makes this question too localized. I appreciate the effort but "well, it doesn't happen to me" isn't an answer.